# How to integrate Beeminder with Authorea?

Tags: collaboration, oauth, beeminder

Over at [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66895/), it has been suggested to integrate [Beeminder](http://www.beeminder.com) with Git services like Github or Bitbucket to gamify academic writing by positive and negative reenforcement. I’m trying out Authorea. Its FAQ has this to say about Git:

> Authorea is based on Git and you can get full access (push/pull) to Authorea articles from external Git repositories, like Github. If you are an experienced Git user, this feature also allows you to work in collaboration with non-Git users sticking to your current writing workflow. You will find directions on how to set up Git access by visiting any of your articles (for which you are an admin) and clicking on Settings → Advanced Settings. Then look for the Git functions and link your paper to a Github repo.

[image: Authorea Advanced Article Settings dialog]

I’m not an experienced Git user, however. 
Is it possible to integrate Beeminder (or a similar service) with Authorea myself?